# Set per-process open file limit in code or in system configuration?

Tags: linux, configuration, file-handling, cross-platform

I am working on an internal application that is maintained by the same people that operate the servers the application runs on. We have noticed, while transitioning from Windows to Linux, that some instances of this application are hitting the default limit on the number of open file handles allowed per process[1].

We want to increase this limit, but the question is where it's best to do it. I see two options:

a) In the system configuration, or

b) By having the application make a syscall when it starts up.

The benefit I can see to a) is that it avoids adding platform-specific code to the application. On the other hand, I also think b) is beneficial because it makes the application less picky in terms of the environment it expects to be run inside.

What would be considered best practise in this case, and why?

[1]: This is not due to a resource leak, but a part of the design of the application – a tradeoff we are willing to make for performance.

Comment: Does the system actually allow option B at the privilege level that the process normally runs on, or would it need to run with elevated privileges to get that syscall accepted? That could have security implications.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would not have the application change the system settings. What if you have two such applications running? they would fight!

Instead, I would have the application check the max allowed value and raise an error or warning if it was too low. Depending on whether it can modify its own behaviour in response.

This way the user is informed of the problem and can configure the server themselves to an appropriate value/upgrade the hardware/install it on a good operating system etc